# How to force Jena API's findShortestPath method to do BFS on <owl#onProperty> instead of <owl#someValuesFrom>?

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena

I am trying to find the shortest path or a path between two nodes in an ontology using Jena's above mentioned method.

Given any two nodes of the ontology, my eventual goal is to create a SPARQL query with this path to query the data at the two nodes and a path is required as SPARQL needs a path as follows (if the 2 nodes are not directly connected)

```
SELECT ?var1 ?var3 
WHERE {
?var1 <someProperty> ?var2.
?var2 <someProperty> ?var3.
}
```

Currently I am getting a path for most of the nodes using Jena, that are connected but the relationship between them is

```
[[http://myontology/Node1, http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf, cbc3c5-d026-49-94d9-e3ba],
[cf3c5-d026-49-94d9-e3ba, http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#someValuesFrom, http://myontology/Node2]]

and so on till Node3.
```

I would like the path to be as

```
[[http://myontology/Node1, http://myontology/myPropertyABC , http://myontology/Node2,]
[http://myontology/Node2, http://myontology/myPropertyXYZ , http://myontology/Node3]]
```

I am currently building the query as

```
SELECT ?var1 ?var3 
WHERE {
?var1 ?x ?var2.
?var2 ?y ?var3.
}
```

This gets me the answer but is a very unoptimized query so I'd prefer to generate the property based query. I tried to walkthrough the shortest path method by priniting it's entire BFS trace and noticed it does search on owl#onProperty. So while supplying the method the onPath argument, how to construct the object to force to only look at onProperty?  (PS- Any other way of achieving the goal is welcomed)

The method signature is,

```java
public static Path findShortestPath( Model m, Resource start, RDFNode end, Predicate<Statement> onPath )
```

Also, Jena fails to find the path at all in a lot of cases when the end node is related to a path in the inverse fashion, for example

```
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 -> Node4 <- Node5.
```

Will reach Node4, but can't get to Node5. This is restricting the ability to address the entire graph and only forward relationships are being addressed.

Any other RDF API's that achieve this, python or java based are also welcome.
(Looked at rdf4j and protege but seems like jena only has this traversal feature)

Would really appreciate any help on this!
Please let me know if additional details are required.